# Classifying two classes when having noise as a third class

Tags: multiclass-classification

Say I have a dataset of e-mails and I want go classify the `newsletter` and `news` emails. One way to do so, is to take all the emails I have, and call stuff that isn't `newsletter` nor `news` for `other` and train a classifier for three classes.

I have trained a binary-classifier which predicts really well `newsletter` or `news` but when I introduce `other` it starts to fall apart.

My first take on this was to train two classifiers; one which trains on `other` and `predict_emails` (where `predict_emails` are emails that are either `newsletter` or `news`), and if that classifier predicts `predict_emails` we then use the binary classifier to predict if it's `newsletter` or `news`.

I think the issue is that `other` contains everything else e.g spam, emails with cooking-recipies etc, thus when we try to find a pattern in `other` then there isn't one as such. Actually the only pattern there is, is that `other` is *not* `news` nor `newsletter`.

Because of that I thought that I would train a model which does the following: "Is it news letter? No. Is it news? No. Then it is something else of which I don't know" but I cannot figure a way to do that (thus my first take which kinda was something like it).

One of the other issue with having a three-class classifier is that say we get a new email with content we have never seen before then the classifier might have confidences of

$[P(\text{news}),P(\text{newsletter}),P(\text{other})] = [0.3,0.3,0.4]$

which in my case I want it to do "I'm very sure it is *not* news and it is *not* newsletter. Then we set it as other" thus it should be $[0.1,0.1,0.8]$.

I know I can just implement it with a logic saying that if there is not a confidence above 0.7, then set it as other, but I would rather make it "robust" and learn if there is a way to handle this "N-class + noise-class" problem

I thought about creating two "one-vs-rest" classifier (`news` vs `other` and `newsletter` vs `other`). If both predictions of these comes out low then we flag it as `other`.